# Firing SQL query on click of button?

Tags: php, mysql, button, increment

I have a simple PHP/MySQL counter which incrementally increases a value in my SQL database. Currently, this script fires every time the page refreshes meaning that the number increases by 1 every time the page is refreshed. I would like to change it so that it only increases when a button is pressed.

Here is my PHP code:

```
<?php

    error_reporting(0);
    include("config.php");

    // get click details based on ID
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM ".$SETTINGS["data_table"]." WHERE id='1'";
    $sql_result = mysql_query ($sql, $connection ) or die ('request "Could not execute SQL query" '.$sql);

    $sql = "UPDATE ".$SETTINGS["data_table"]." SET clicks=clicks+1 WHERE id='1'";
    $sql_result = mysql_query ($sql, $connection ) or die ('request "Could not execute SQL query" '.$sql);

?>
```

And here is the button I would like to tie it to:

```
<div class="content">
    <span id="button">Click Me</span>
</div>
```

Any ideas on how I can accomplish this? Thanks!

Comment: submit a form, or use an ajax call.

Comment: or add onClick javascript function

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: You can use a `GET` method (if as a plain `href`) or make a `submit` (POST) type of button in conjunction with a function, then using `if(isset($_POST['function_button_1'])) { SQL HERE }`

Comment: Given that the request is changing data, it should **only** occur via POST.  GETs should be free of effects other than serving the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Option#1 (Easy):

Reload the page on clicking the button:

```
<span id="button" onclick="javascript: location.reload();">Click Me</span>
```

Option#2:

1. Put the query portion in separate file (say **inc.php**)
2. Use an AJAX call on the onclick event of the button span. (You can use JQuery)

Here is an example with jQuery AJAX:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
function inc_counter()
{
$.ajax({
    url: "inc.php",
    context: document.body
    }).done(function() {
    alert('incremented');
    });
    return false;
}
-->
</script>

<span id="button" onclick="javascript:return inc_counter();">Click Me</span>
```

Comment: I went with option 2 because that looks like what I am looking for, however, the increment does not seem to be firing when I click the button. I placed my PHP code above into inc.php and I see "GET inc.php 200 OK 4ms" in the developer console when I click the button, but it does not increase the integer in the SQL database.

Comment: In inc.php try to print a success/error (mysql_error()) output. Then print the response in the alert: .done(function(msg) {
    alert(msg);
    });